# Some commands gdb/mi

Tags: gdb

I need read from gdb by mi commands the source code and local variables: type and values.

I use  `list 1,50000` for source code.
Is there any mi command?

I use `-stack-list-locals` but not recieve the type of var.
How can I do it?

Thanks
xavi

Answer (score 0):

For read source code:
send `-file-list-exec-source-file` and read directly.

For recieve type of vars:
Add `--simple-values` or `2` to `-stack-list-locals command`